# Remove image background in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, edge-detection

In this example of edge detection:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/edge-detection.html#buh9ylp-13

How would I remove the gray background in the grayscale image at the beginning?

Comment: your question makes no sense, what do you mean remove? you want it to be opaque or something?

Comment: that background is not black or unique color

Comment: @GameOfThrows as in make the coins a cutout. When I blend a similar image with another the gray surface the coins sit on is still in the image and I want to remove it.

Comment: @ddb sorry changed to gray.

Comment: you want to use the edge detection and then write the image as a png file with transparency - this would be the cut out of the coins' edges you want.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the background befor you apply an edge detector makes no sense as the more or less homogeneous low frequency background will result in a zero gradient anyway. It won't improve the results of your edgedetection.

If you only want to cut out the coins to put them on a different background simply apply a global threshold

[image: original image]

[image: threshold]

Remove thos tiny speckles with some morphological operators and blur the mask so you won't have fringed coin edges

[image: cleanup]

Apply some logical operations to mask the original image

[image: masked image]

Comment: What function does the thresholding?

Comment: Applying a threshold is just using comparison operator (like `<`) and a threshold value.

Comment: Still not sure what to do, I can read in the image with imread, but what do i replace the values with so that they disappear? I can just change the grayscale saturation it looks like.

Comment: @J.Doe do yourself a favour and read a book on image processing fundamentals. you will have a very hard time if you don't have at least some knowledge. knowing how to use google also helps!  http://de.mathworks.com/discovery/image-thresholding.html